# searching mysql db for lat/long OR by name of item

Tags: php, mysql, geocoding

I just wanted some advice really.
I am building a project where by I want to allow the users to search either by location or by a reference say restaurant name from the data that may exist in my db already.

Currently I have part implemented the location search where by the user can type in location say "nw5" and I then go get the approx lat/long and query my db with them coords. All good and works well.

I want to now add in a feature where the user can say "I know the restaurant name" - whacks it in and brings back the results accordingly.

I am sort of lost on how best to play this tbh.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks

Raj

Comment: What did you consider so far?

Comment: hey - initial thoughts was - check to see if I got back any results from the Gmaps API against that value, if so search db against lat/long received ELSE search the db for the value. I am trying to implement an autocomplete feature that is generated from the db so that I get a search result.

Comment: actually tastecard.co.uk is a good feature to look at

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some client-side magic for something like an autocomplete - jqueryui.com has a good one. Then you'll need a server-side ajax handler to run a query. Here's one I use, this is Doctrine but you could whip together a similar sql query:

```
function getLocByLabelChunk($chunkFromUser) {
        $lower = strtolower($chunkFromUser);
        $ls = str_split($lower);
        $first = strtoupper($ls[0]);
        $firstUp = $first;
        for ($i=1; $i < count($ls); $i++) { 
            $firstUp .= $ls[$i];
        }

        $dql = "
            SELECT l.locID as lID, l.label, l.label as value
            FROM Entity\Location l
            WHERE 
                l.label LIKE ?2
                OR l.label LIKE ?3
                OR l.label LIKE ?4
            )
        ";

        $q = $em->createQuery($dql);
        $q->setParameter(2,"%" . $chunkFromUser. "%");
        $q->setParameter(3,"%" . $lower . "%");
        $q->setParameter(4,"%" . $firstUp . "%");
        $locations = $q->getArrayResult();
        return $locations;
    }
```